# Run an App made in React native in an Emulator Android

Tags: android, react-native, ubuntu

S.O. Ubuntu: 20.04

I'm trying to run an app that I downloaded, but when I try to `yarn run android`

The next message:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-community_async-storage'.
> Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

This is the code of `buildScript` in the file `build.gradle`

```
buildScript {

    if (project == rootProject) {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you install this library?

Comment: This is my first time with RN, but I Run, Yarn, in theory, when that command download all the librarys of Package.json .it's not like that?